# PHP mysql crosstable with variable fields

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with making a pivot table/cross table. At the end I would like to edit it inline, but first I'd like to make at least the table.

In table ' tarifs' I have an Id, TarifCode and TarifDescr
Like:

```
1, A, Overnight
2, P, Room
3, V, Adult No discount
etc.
```

At some point in my application I fill out a start date, an end date and for the applicable tarifcodes a value (amount).
Like:

```
2012-02-05, 2012-02-09, A:1, P:0, V:2
```

After submit an SQL query fills a table 'Occupacion', that exists of ID, Date, TarifCode, Value, like:

```
1, 2012-02-05, A, 1
2, 2012-02-05, V, 2
3, 2012-02-06, A, 1
4, 2012-02-06, V, 2
5, 2012-02-07, A, 1
6, 2012-02-07, V, 2
7, 2012-02-08, A, 1
8, 2012-02-08, V, 2
9, 2012-02-09, A, 1
10, 2012-02-09, V, 2
```

Here is my question:
How can I create a query (or view) that gives me the next output:

```
-- 2012-02-05 | 2012-02-06 | 2012-02-07 | 2012-02-08 | 2012-02-09
A           1            1            1            1            1
V           2            2            2            2            2
```

In most of the posts related to this topic the values are known. In my case sometimes there is no TarifCode A used or there is a new TarifCode created.

At the very end I would like to make this in a JSON-style so I can use it for inline editing in a grid. Maybe someone has experience with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to perform this using SQL, then you can *pivot* the data in MySQL with an aggregate function and a `CASE` expression. This will take the `date` values and convert them to columns:

```
select tarifcode,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-05' then value end) `2012-02-05`,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-06' then value end) `2012-02-06`,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-07' then value end) `2012-02-07`,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-08' then value end) `2012-02-08`,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-09' then value end) `2012-02-09`
from yourtable
group by tarifcode
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7030d/2)

If the dates are unknown, then you can use a prepared statement similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when Date = ''',
      Date,
      ''' then value end) AS `',
      Date, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  yourtable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT TarifCode, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM yourtable 
                  GROUP BY TarifCode');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7030d/3). The result of both queries is:

```
| TARIFCODE | 2012-02-05 | 2012-02-06 | 2012-02-07 | 2012-02-08 | 2012-02-09 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         A |          1 |          1 |          1 |          1 |          1 |
|         V |          2 |          2 |          2 |          2 |          2 |
```

Edit, If you want to join to another table, then you can use something similar to this:

```
select 
  t.tarifcode,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-05' then value end) `2012-02-05`,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-06' then value end) `2012-02-06`,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-07' then value end) `2012-02-07`,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-08' then value end) `2012-02-08`,
  max(case when Date = '2012-02-09' then value end) `2012-02-09`
from tarifs t
left join yourtable y
  on t.tarifcode = y.tarifcode
group by t.tarifcode
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12e1d/1)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Bluefeet! I forgot something, that's why I came back. Maybe you can hint me again?
I would like to join the TarifCode table, so all TarifCodes are left and all dates (indeed unknown at forehand) on top. Only the fields that has a value are filled. The other ones are empty.
Is that possible?
Again many thanks for your help!

Roy

Comment: @RoyVissers please see my edit, you will just use a join to the other table

Comment: @RoyVissers glad you figured it out! :)